# How to create schema containing list of objects using Avro?

Tags: java, schema, avro

Does anyone knows how to create Avro schema which contains list of objects of some class?

I want my generated classes to look like below :

```
class Child {
    String name;
}

class Parent {
    list<Child> children;
}
```

For this, I have written part of schema file but do not know how to tell Avro to create list of objects of type `Children`?

My schema file looks like below :

```
{
    "name": "Parent",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"children",
            "type":{
                "name":"Child",
                "type":"record",
                "fields":[
                    {"name":"name", "type":"string"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

Now problem is  that I can mark field `children` as either `Child` type or array but do not know how to mark it as a `array of objects of type Child` class?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to use [array](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Arrays) type for creating the list.
Following is the updated schema that handles your usecase.

```
{
    "name": "Parent",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"children",
            "type":{
                "type": "array",  
                "items":{
                    "name":"Child",
                    "type":"record",
                    "fields":[
                        {"name":"name", "type":"string"}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider using List instead since I've encountered NPE's when deserializing String arrays.

Comment: @qwetty Does the data need to be nested like this? What if we had to have multiple fields of the same type? The definition of the child type would need to be repeated? Seems cleaner to separate the types

Comment: @Kapil what will be default value for this?

Comment: The Avro-to-Hive documentation lists the avro type as "list" instead of "array". https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe#AvroSerDe-AvrotoHivetypeconversion Is it possible that the Hive documentation is incorrect ?

Answer (score 10):

I had following classes and Avro maven plugin generated two classes accordingly :

```
public class Employees{
    String accountNumber;
    String address;
    List<Account> accountList;    
}

public class Account {
    String accountNumber;
    String id;
}
```

Avro file format :

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.mypackage",
    "name": "AccountEvent",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "accountNumber",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "accountList",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items":{
                    "name": "Account",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields":[
                        {   "name": "accountNumber",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {   "name": "id",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm quite dumb / literal in my readings so I have to ask maybe obvious questions: In the Avro file format, does `"name": "AccountEvent"` correspond to the `Employees` class? In other words, would it be more accurate to say `"name": "Employees"`?

Answer (score 2):

Array as type

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "jamesMedice",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "columns",
        "type": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "columnValues",
                "fields": [{
                        "name": "personId",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "email",
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "null"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```