# What Serde to use for Avro array type? (Kafka)

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I've registered the following Avro schema for a topic:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": "com.example.User"
}
```

where `com.example.User` is of type *record* and is defined in a separate file.

I know that [`SpecificAvroSerde`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/avro/SpecificAvroSerde.java) can be used to serialize/ deserialize a [`SpecificRecord`](https://github.com/justinsb/avro/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/avro/specific/SpecificRecord.java), but what Serdes should you use for an array of records?

Comment: SpecificRecord schema can be an array, AFAIK

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Might you be able to share some code to show me how to create a SpecificRecord with an array schema? I'm not quite sure what you mean. A SpecificRecord can have a *field* which is an array, but surely it can't be an array itself?

Comment: Well, I've never actually registered an array schema into the registry, only an object that holds a list of other record items. But still, `SpecificData` return a `List` class when the Schema is of type Array - https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/specific/SpecificData.java#L266

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create schema containing list of objects using Avro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076786/how-to-create-schema-containing-list-of-objects-using-avro)

Comment: Thanks, I'd actualy already seen this. But I have registered an array type to a topic, not a record type *containing* an array field. So it's a little different.